# How to add fields to file entities?

Tags: 8, entities, files

In Drupal 7, the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module allowed you to add fields on a file entity. I don't see this ability out of the box in Drupal 8.

How can I add fields to file entities in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3):

In D8 the module [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) provides this feature, same as in D7. It was required by Media, so you probably installed it without noticing in D7.

The new Media package for D8 doesn't use this anymore. Instead it uses a new media entity for the extra information. There is work going on to put the media entity in core for 8.3:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2825215

Comment: So for Drupal 8 it's better to go with the [Media Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) instead of File Entity by now?  Media Entity will not be in core before [8.4](https://www.drupal.org/node/2831274)

Comment: Yes, definitely, see this answer from the maintainer of File Entity @Berdir http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228260/47547